# How add object to session with spring and get it with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, security, session

I want add an object (model) to the current session with spring and get it in all the code (java + html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want ControllerAdvice, but your question is not very specific.

ControllerAdvice is a glorified interceptor.  It can inject data into the spring mvc model for every view with `@ModelAttribute`.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"com.concretepage.controller"} )
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {
    @ModelAttribute
        public void globalAttributes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Message for every view");
        }
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, look at filters and interceptors.